# Using OffsetDateTime with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, nodatime

I'm trying to map NodaTime's `OffsetDateTime` type to SQL Server but I'm not sure how to solve the impedance between NodaTime's `OffsetDateTime` and SQL Server's `DateTimeOffset` types.

The main problem I have is getting LINQ support to work correctly because `OffsetDateTime` does not have comparison operators such as `<`. The systems also differ on how they handle equality. NodaTime considers both the instant in time and the offset while SQL Server only considers the instant in time.

`2015-12-24 11:18+01:00` and `2015-12-24 10:18+00:00` are considered equal in SQL Server, but are not equal in NodaTime.

I considered using `ICompositeUserType` to store the the UTC date/time and the offset in separate columns (similar to before SQL Server 2008) but `OffsetDateTime` does not have a UTC/Instant property. As such I can't see how to get `date.ToInstant()` in LINQ queries to map correctly to a property in the `ICompositeUserType`.

Comment: First, What are you trying to do? If you converted both values to NodaTime instants, they *would* be equal - they do refer to the same instant. Do you really want them to behave as different values?

Comment: Second, NHibernat *maps* your classes to the *database*. You can't use semantics that aren't supported by the database type. LINQ or any ORM do not change the database's functionality, they simply make it easier to map between objects and tables. Any other use is a serious smell

Comment: I want to use NodaTime's `OffsetDateTime` type in my models and map them to either SQL Server's `DateTimeOffset` or to 2 columns, a `DateTime` storing the UTC value, and an offset.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`OffsetDateTime` should map to a SQL Server `datetimeoffset`.  NHibernate's support for custom type mappings via the `IUserType` [as described in this article](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-nhibernate-type) will be essential to making this work.

Though `OffsetDateTime` doesn't directly implement `IComparable`, you can use `OffsetDateTime.Comparer.Instant` to compare them.  That still may be difficult to use in LINQ queries, but it's one route to explore.

Someone should probably write an NHibernate-NodaTime integration package to make this simpler.  Considering I've done this before for [RavenDB](https://github.com/mj1856/RavenDB-NodaTime) and for [Dapper](https://github.com/mj1856/Dapper-NodaTime), I'll take it under consideration. :)

Sorry, I don't have a better actual "do this" kind of answer for you.

---

**UPDATE**

I started working on this, and successfully built an `IUserType` for `OffsetDateTime`, but it doesn't work for comparison operators - for the very reason you described.  I believe the solution involves extending the linq provider similar to the technique described [in this blog post](http://www.primordialcode.com/blog/post/nhibernate-3-extending-linq-provider-fix-notsupportedexception/).  I don't have a complete working example yet, but I will update here when I do.

Ultimately, you won't be able to write:

```
session.Query<Foo>().Where(x => x.SomeODT > value)
```

Because `OffsetDateTime` doesn't have the comparison operators so it won't compile.

Instead, the LINQ provider should be extended to support something like this:

```
session.Query<Foo>().Where(x => OffsetDateTime.Comparer.Instant.Compare(x.SomeODT, value) > 0)
```

Or perhaps more cleanly as:

```
session.Query<Foo>().Where(x => x.SomeODT.ToInstant() > value.ToInstant())
```

Or perhaps both.  Both will compile, but will throw an exception without proper support in the LINQ provider.

---

**SECOND UPDATE**

Someone beat me to it.  There are now a set of extensions for NHibernate to support Noda Time data types [in this project](https://github.com/MatthewRudolph/Airy-Nhibernate-Extensions). :)

Comment: @JonSkeet (if you're reading this) take note of how not having a default comparer for `OffsetDateTime` causes issues in contexts like this one.  Also, note that comparison by *local time* would be impossible to implement here, because ultimately the LINQ would be translated to a SQL statement, and SQL *always* compares `datetimeoffset` types by their UTC equivalent.

Comment: Yup, I'm reading :) So do you think `OffsetDateTime` should have a default comparison which is by instant, like SQL? Note that it wouldn't be compatible with equality, which would compare offset as well as instant... what does SQL do about that?

Comment: I got a working implementation of that concept https://gist.github.com/chilversc/d1ba1fdbae58d8a13704 by using a custom `LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry` and handling the `ToInstant` method. In my implementation I used a composite user type as its a legacy DB that has a separate UTC date/time and offset columns.

Comment: @JonSkeet MSSQL sorts `DateTimeOffset` by its instant in time (i.e. ignores the offset) and considers two `DateTimeOffsets` as equal if they are the same instant. Having a comparer could make working with Linq and MSSQL simpler as then you could have `query.OrderBy(x => x.CreateAt)`. Only thing I'm not sure about is how much code makes the assumption that when `CompareTo == 0` then `Equals == true`.

Comment: @ChrisChilvers: We already have `OffsetDateTime.Comparer.Instant` as shown by Matt; you could use `query.OrderBy(x => x.CreateAt, OffsetDateTime.Comparer.Instant)`. If you mean in terms of implementing `IComparable<T>`... I'll think about it a bit more. I would prefer that `Equals` still takes the offset into account, but I can see how a natural ordering would only be by instant. As you say, having equality and ordering do different things is a bit odd.

Comment: I thought of that, but that raises an issue if you have `query.OrderBy(x => x.CreateAt, OffsetDateTime.Comparer.Local)`. I have no way to tell which comparer was used, and most linq providers do not support that form of `OrderBy`.